# geometric series: $a_1 = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i, a_2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

In the given geometric series: $a_1 = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i, a_2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$.

The general member is: $cos(60+180(n-1)) + sin(60+180(n-1))i$

How can I prove that for any natural $n$ the sum of the first $6n$ members is $0$?

**Attempt:** I think I can prove it with induction, but I'm not sure what the $q$ is.

(I'm not allowed to use de Moivre.)

Comment: I don't see a "geometric series", but only two numbers. Can you clarify ?

Comment: I edited the description @TheSilverDoe

Comment: It's still not a geometric series, but if such a series had the first $6n$ terms sum to $0$ you'd need its common ratio to be a sixth root of unity.

Comment: I don't think that's a geometric series.

Comment: The expression you have for the general term is not correct

Comment: "but I'm not sure what the $q$ is." We also can't know what the $q$ is since there's no mention other than that one in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be a geometric sequence with $a_1,a_2$ given as above. Then we have $a_n =q a_{n-1}$ for $n \ge 2.$ Hence

$$q= \frac{a_2}{a_1}=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i.$$

Thus

$$q^6=1.$$
Therefore, for $n \in \mathbb N,$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{6n}a_k=a_1 \sum_{k=0}^{6n}q^k.$$

It is your turn to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{6n}q^k=0.$$